# Determining if a function is harmonic in a fast way

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

> Determine which function is harmonic in $\mathbb R^2$:
>   $$\text{a) } y^2 \qquad \text{b) }x^2 + y^2\qquad \text{c) } e^x\qquad \text{d) }\operatorname{Im}((x + iy)^5)$$

I had this question come up in an exam, so I checked the first three functions, which are easier to differentiate, and by exclusion I determined that the last one was the only harmonic function.

However, to be really sure I wrote the Pascal triangle up to the sixth row, calculated the binomial power and differentiated the last one as well. It did indeed prove to be harmonic, but I feel like I wasted a lot of time.

Is there a faster way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: The real part and imaginary part of a holomorphic function are both harmonic.

Comment: Right, so it is sufficient to show that $f(z) = z$ is holomorphic, which is trivial. Thanks a lot!